# What is the conventional way of defining macros in main.c that are needed in other header files?

Tags: c

For example I have a can.h header file that contains

```
   #ifdef MC
    extern int speed;
    // many more variables and function prototypes
   #endif
```

EDIT: I would want an option for the user to define MC that enables such variable and function prototypes. It is to be defined in C main alongside include directives (e.g. #define MC) however, other header files cannot link to main.c. Instead, i ended up defining such macros in can.h header itself. All i can think is writing a main.h too where can.h will include main.h. are there other ways to go around this problem?

Comment: The conventional way is to not do that. If you need preprocessor symbols, type declarations, or other content shared among source files, put it in a header file.

Comment: Pick a name, any name.  "globals.h" jumps to mind.

Comment: So, what is this question about? Macros? Or global variables? The title suggests it is about defining *macros* in `main.c`, but the it talks about *linking*, which would apply to *variables* only...

Comment: Edited the question. sorry for writing a question that is not clear. I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, but perhaps you want this:

```
/* in file can.h */
extern int speed;
```

and then

```
/* in file main.c */
#include "can.h"

int speed;
```

The header `can.h` just *declares* the existence of `speed` so that other modules can refer to it as an external symbol. The storage for this object is then allocated in main.c, when you write the the *definition* of `speed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a configuration header that has all the macros that you want defined and `#include` it in every header, or you can define configuration macros on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include` - Then you get those bits that you require

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion is simply file content insertion by the preprocessor, anything declared or defined prior to inclusion will be defined in the include file.  So:

```
#define MC
#include "can.h"
```

While that achieves what you have asked, I would not necessarily recommend it however, and might question the design.

Answer (score -1):

You can have such macro added at your project level. 
Such macro are also known as Preprocessor definitions. Visual studio provides such definition in project settings/configurations.. 
So you can have it added there and compile the solution for including mentioned declarations or remove it if you don't want to include it.
Adding the screen shot.
[image]